# How to properly send file to browser?

Tags: php

I want to send a file directly to browser:

```
<?php
@ini_set('error_reporting', 0);

@apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');


@ob_implicit_flush();

$file = 'ORG.iso';

$quoted    = sprintf('"%s"', addcslashes(basename($file), '"\\'));
$file_size = filesize($file);


header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $quoted); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');

header('Content-Length: ' . $file_size);

@ob_end_flush();

set_time_limit(0);

$f = fopen($file, 'r');
while (!feof($f))
{
    $buff = fread($f, 204800);
    echo $buff;
    sleep(1);
}
fclose($f);
```

It shows correct file size in Firefox and Chrome right after visitor enters the link. However it does not work in jDownloader. It seems like jDownloader is waiting for the whole script to end.
When I try a normal, static file from the same webserver- jDownloader shows file size instantly.
So obviously something is wrong with my script.

Comment: You shouldn't be oppressing your errors (`@`). Handle them properly.

Comment: @Darren Sure, but I am trying to show a simplest possible demo

Comment: Why not use a static file then? What's with the `fread` loop over `readfile`? Why not utilize X-Sendfile at least? Perhaps jDownloader expects your scripts to understand byte Range: requests? Did you debug the request headers and log?

Comment: @mario I need to send data generated dynamically. This is just to show the problem. I logged headers and jDownloader did not send any Range reguests.